# Does (->) have a data constructor?

Tags: haskell

I know `(->)` type is defined as `data (->) t1 t2`. I wonder is there a data constructor function for the `(->)` type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `(->)` does not have a data constructor, as functions are not algebraic data types. The fact that ghci says

```
Prelude> :inf (->)
data (->) t1 t2     -- Defined in ‘GHC.Prim’
```

is a bit of a lie, because that is not how `(->)` is being defined. In fact, there is no definition around, as functions are a very primitive notion.

In some sense, a lambda expression `\x -> e` (or, equivalently, a function definition) is the “constructor” of values of type `a -> b`, but you cannot pattern match on that. Instead, you use function applications (`f e`) to deconstruct (“use”) a function.

Comment: (...but you can still use `seq` to force evaluation of a function to WHNF.)

Comment: "... ,as functions are not algebraic data types..." hits the nail on the head. The next logical question then would be what's purpose of including data (->) t1 t2 in GHC.Prim? Just to make the types complete?

Comment: `:info` has to show something, and I could imagine that haddock wants some (fake) `data (->)` to attach documentation to.

Comment: Why do we say functions are not algebraic data types? A function of type `a -> b` has `b^a` possible values, just as `Either a b` has `a+b` possible values and `(a, b)` has `a*b` possible values. Of course the way we work with functions is different, but they seem to me to fit into the same sort of algebra.

Comment: There are actually more functions, if you count (partially) undefined onces.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner So? If you want to allow undefined you are just implicitly lifting from `a -> b` to `a -> Either ⊥ b`. And likewise we can do the same with other algebraic data types. I don't see how functions are special in this regard.

Comment: A crucial property of data types is that you can match on them and figure out which constructor is used. You cannot do that on functions, because that would amount to deciding the equivalence between arbitrary programs, which is not something computers can do (halting problem…).

Comment: I'd say the inability to patten match on function types is more a *symptom* of it not having data constructors rather than the other way around. You can't pattern-match on `IO` values, either, but no one claims they aren't algebraic datatypes.

Comment: `newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))`. Certainly not a data type.

Comment: "they seem to me to fit into the same sort of algebra". Definitely! I don't think anyone claims function types are not "_algebraic_", it's just that they're not _data_ types. Sections 4.1.2 and 4.2.1 of the Haskell 2010 Report define "data" and "function" types as two different classes of types, and that distinction is important when it comes to other parts of the language; for one, as @JoachimBreitner shows, Haskell does allow you to pattern-match on any _data_ value (as long as you manage to get the constructor in scope!), while it disallows pattern-matching on _function_ values.